# Js twitch bot "Cannot send anonymous messages."

Tags: node.js, chatbot, twitch

So I started to make a twitch chatbot. It has a really basic script from a tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijl3GUHvKIw) but, when I try to send messages with the bot I got this error:

```js
(node:10688) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Cannot send anonymous messages.
(node:10688) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict

(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

Can somebody help me how to fix this? (I just started code in js so I don't know a lot about it)

EDIT: Here is my code:

```js
const tmi = require('tmi.js');

const option = {
  options: {
    debug: true,
  },
  connection: {
    cluster: 'aws',
    reconnect: true,
  },
  indentity: {
    username: 'xxxxxx',
    password: 'oauth:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  },
  channels: ['ady_studios'],
};

const client = new tmi.client(option);

client.connect();

client.on('connected', (adress, port) => {
  client.action('Ady Studios is online!');
});

client.on('chat', (channel, user, message, self) => {
  if (message === '!game') {
    client.action('No. its not play time.');
  }
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO @Blender Ue, do share your code so members can reproduce your problem. You can read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more on how to ask on SO

Comment: Ok. I shared the code. Please be patient cuz this was my first question. (I am also from hungary thats why my english could be bad)

Comment: Don't worry, SO is a loving and welcoming community. We help one another here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in `option` object, instead of `option.indentity` should be `option.identity`. Try with

```
const tmi = require("tmi.js");

const option = {
  options: {
    debug: true
  },
  connection: {
    cluster: "aws",
    reconnect: true
  },
  // you have a typo here, indentity idenity
  // so tmi is defaulting to join channel as anonymous user
  // indentity: {
  //   username: "xxxxxx",
  //   password: "oauth:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  // },
  identity: {
      username: "xxxxxx",
      password: "oauth:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
  channels: ["ady_studios"]
};

const client = new tmi.client(option);

client.connect();

client.on("connected", (adress, port) => {
  client.action("Ady Studios is online!");
});

client.on("chat", (channel, user, message, self) => {
  if (message === "!game") {
    client.action("No. its not play time.");
  }
});
```

Remember to put your actual username and password

Comment: Yeah i just replaced it with xxxx so nobody can stole my usr or pswd